# presentModalViewController changed on IOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

I have a MainWindow.xib file, which is just blank. And I assigned a delegate to it.
In delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, I added a viewController to a UINavigationController and added UINavigationController to UITabbarController, which use presentModalViewController to display another view. It works fine on IOS4, but after I updated to IOS5, it just show the MainWindow.xib view unless after I pressed home button.And then another view will pop up.

```
//Main
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"Delegate");
    return retVal;
}

//Delegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    HomeFirstViewController *homeFirstVC = [[HomeFirstViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *home = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeFirstVC];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:home animated:NO];           
    [homeFirstVC release];
    [home release];
}
```

Comment: You don't want to be presenting UINavigationController instances modally, that's not what they are for. It is a specialized subclass of UIViewController which handles navigation between UIViewControllers.